Return a 3D Numpy array from Pandas grouped DataFrame
I'm attempting to convert a grouped Pandas DataFrame to a 3D numpy array, where every DataFrame cell is mapped to a 1D numpy array. I'm expecting a 3D array of shape (4, 2, 3), but instead I get a shape (4, 2) 2D array of shape (3,) 1D arrays.
Simplified example:
example_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["A", True, True], 
     ["A", True, False], 
     ["B", False, True], 
     ["B", False, False]],
    columns=["grp", "col1", "col2"],
)


def mapper(val):
    return np.ones(3) if val is True else np.zeros(3)


result = (
    example_df.groupby(["grp"])
    .apply(lambda df: df.map(mapper), include_groups=False)
    .to_numpy()
)

print(type(result))
print(type(result[0]))
print(type(result[0][0]))
print(type(result[0][0][0]))
print(result.shape)
print(result[0, 0].shape)

Output:
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
(4, 2)
(3,)


result is a 2d array, object dtype.  The elements are 1d numeric arrays..

Use explode and reshape:
result = (
    example_df.groupby(["grp"])
    .transform(lambda df: df.map(mapper))
    .explode(["col1", "col2"])
    .to_numpy()
    .reshape(4, 2, 3)
)

[[[1.0 1.0 1.0]
  [1.0 1.0 1.0]]

 [[1.0 0.0 1.0]
  [0.0 1.0 0.0]]

 [[0.0 1.0 0.0]
  [1.0 0.0 1.0]]

 [[0.0 0.0 0.0]
  [0.0 0.0 0.0]]]

Your print statements will output:
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
(4, 2, 3)
(3,)


Add this line above your print statements:
result = np.stack(result.ravel()).reshape(4, 2, 3)


Give this a try, or use it for inspiration.
Your Code:
result = (
    example_df.groupby(["grp"])
    .apply(lambda df: df.map(mapper), include_groups=False)
    .to_numpy()
)

Instead try this code instead. May need to tweak.
result = example_df[["col1", "col2"]].applymap(mapper).values

result = np.stack(result).reshape(4, 2, 3)

print(result.shape)  # Should print (4, 2, 3)
print(result)

I think the issue with your original code is how the 'apply' function/operations handle the data. Tell me if it works and/or if there are any problems.

applymap is deprecated, and example_df[["col1", "col2"]].applymap(mapper).values just produces an array with the same shape and contents as my example.
The reshape fails with cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (4,2,3).
